# How to map a OneToOne with ZeroOrOneToOne back reference in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-one

I have a legacy app which has an entity relationship that looks like this. I changed the names of the fields to less realistic values and reduced to only the relevant fields.

[image: ER]

```sql
CREATE TABLE `billing_target` (
  `billingTargetID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `targetType` char(5) NOT NULL,
  `targetID` int(11) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`billingTargetID`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Client` (
  `clientID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200),
  `color` varchar(200),
  `shape` varchar(200)
  PRIMARY KEY (`clientID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_client_billingTarget` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`clientID`) 
    REFERENCES `billing_target` (`targetID`)
);
```

My most current attempt which causes an issue when saving as it gives a null entity key exception.

```java
@Data
@Entity
public class BillingTarget implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "billingTargetID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "targetID", nullable = false)
    private Integer targetID;

    @Column(name = "targetType", nullable = false)
    private String type;

}

@Data
@Entity
public class Client implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "clientID")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "clientID")
    @MapsId("targetID")
    private BillingTarget billingTarget;

    private String name;
    private String color;
    private String shape;
}
```

Here's the PlantUML code if interested

```
@startuml
hide circle

entity BillingTarget {
  * billingTargetID <<generated>>
  --
  * targetType
  * targetID <<unique>>
}

entity Client {
  * clientID <<fk>>
  --
  * name
  color
  shape
}

BillingTarget ||--o| Client : "targetID:clientID"
@enduml
```

I was already thinking of using a `MappedSuperclass` but right now it is only one type (though it could be more).  Second the billing target may be `zero` and not `null` as there's a NOT NULL constraint already present.